# Is it on-topic to ask for feedback on a textbook proposal?

Tags: discussion

I have a textbook proposal currently being considered for publication.  The tentative title of the book is *Secondary Mathematics for Mathematicians and Educators*, and as the title suggests it focuses on the mathematics of the secondary curriculum from an advanced perspective.  The book has three anticipated audiences:

1. Preservice teachers near the end of their undergraduate studies (for example, in a capstone course)
2. Masters-level students in Mathematics who are primarily interested in education at the secondary or community college level
3. Doctoral students in Mathematics Education

I imagine that the plan for the book might be of interest to members of the MESE community, and that they might have some input for me as the project moves forward. Specifically I would like to share (a link to) the proposal for the book, and ask the following questions on the main site:

1. Would you use a book like this, and with what audience?
2. What features or topics would you like to see added to this book that do not already appear in the proposal?

I'm wondering whether such a post would be considered appropriate on the main site.  On the one hand I have no doubt that the *content* of the book would be perfectly on-topic; on the other hand, I would not like to come across as primarily motivated by self-promotion.

Comment: Thanks for asking. I have not quite made up my mind yet but want to offer a quick opinion as meta here might not have all that much readership. My main concern would be that this seems rather opinion based and poll-like. However it might be possible to avoid this a little still keeping the spirit. For example "1. For which (specific) courses would this book make a suitable textbook? 2. What if anything could be added to make it more useful in that context?"

Comment: Another option is to bring this up as a discussion in chat.  Unfortunately, only a handful of users seem to visit chat.